# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application [pycrypto]

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

I installed PyCrypto on python 64-bit version on windows 10 64-bit version
when i type :
`from Crypto.Hash import SHA512` 
everything is working fine and i can calculate the hash

but when i type: `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`,or any Crypto.PublicKey library i am getting errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 78, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 7, in <module>
File "c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1inbe0\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am new to installing and using python packages and libraries.
[here you can see that the library is included correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT2nd.jpg)

can someone help me with this error please?